# LINQ Query to retrieve items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

So I am using EF, I have the following entities:

- `Website`
- `Sector`
- `Product`
- `Attribute`
- `AttributeTag`

The relationships are as follow:

[image]

I need to retrieve something that is not directly linked to the table. Such as products which needs a `Sector` object in order to retrieve only the specific `Products` using something such as `sector.Products`.

But what if I need to retrieve all `Products` under a given `Website` instead of it's parent `Sector` ?

In my specific situation, my questions are:
1) How can I retrieve all the products given a specific `website_id` - (Disregarding the sector)
2) How can I retrieve all the products that have a specific `tag_id` + `website_id`. (Also retrieve it's corresponding `Attribute`)

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've got both side navigation properties :

you will have a `List<Sector> SectorList` in Product Entity.

you will have a `List<Product> ProductList` in Sector Entity.

(`sectors_products` won't be present as an entity, as it's not needed in an object world).

you will have a `Website Website` in Sector Entity

you will have a `List<AttributeTag> AttributeTagList` in Product Entity;

(`products_tags` won't be present as an entity, as it's not needed in an object world).

1) something like :

```
var result = ProductEntities
             .Where(p => p.SectorList
                         .Any(s => s.WebSite.Id == <your_website_id>)
                    );
```

2) something like  (taking 1) as base query)

```
result = result
         .Where(p => p.AttributeTagList
                     .Any(at => at.Id == <your_tag_id>)
               );
```

or all in one

```
var result = ProductEntitites
              .Where(p => 
                        p.SectorList.Any(s => s.WebSite.Id == <your_website_id>) &&
                        p.AttributeTagList.Any(at => at.Id == <your_tag_id>)
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

The relationships in your schema form a pathway. If you want to figure out the relationships between two entity sets, you have to follow that pathway and query all the entities in between.

```
var part1 = (from w in Websites
             from s in Sectors
             from p in s.Products
             where s.Website equals w
             && w.website_id equals web_id
             select p).Distinct();

var part2 = from p in part1
            let attr = p.Attributes.Where(a => a.tag_id + web_id == target_val)
            where attr.Any()
            select new { p, attr };
```

If I understand your schema correctly, that should pull down the data to answer both parts of your question.